# Can MSFT Azure pipeline connect to Bitbucket as source control system then build and deploy the build artifacts to on-premise server?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I've gotten the capability about "deploy the build artifacts to on-premise server". But I am not sure if Azure pipeline can connect to Bitbucket to fetch the code then do the build.

Comment: yeah, why not? cant you see bitbucket in sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, try to add a new service connection and grant permission for your pipelines. 
Here is how you can connect it:

[image]

From this point, you should be able to create your pipelines from the code on bitbucket.

Comment: Thanks a lot kgalic for prompt answer!

Comment: @FastLearner Hi friend, it seems that **kgalic's** answer makes some help for your issue. If his answer resolves your issue, you could [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that more members can benefit from this useful info! And if the issue persists, feel free to let us know. Just a reminder :)